# How to filter spotlight search results

Tags: macos, mac, osx-el-capitan, spotlight

I use spotlight search to open some applications or look out for definition of english words. But now whenever I type some word to look out for definition, many files are visible as result (*which are unnecessary in my case*).

I want spotlight to search only for apps and definitions. How can I restrict spotlight to do so?

Thanks.

Edit: Mac version is 10.11.1 (El capitan)

Answer (score 1):

As long as you are running OSX 10.10 or older, you can use [Flashlight](https://github.com/nate-parrott/Flashlight) to better dictate what functions you want spotlight to do.

Comment: mine is 10.11.1

Comment: There is a new fork of Flashlight that does support 10.11 and newer.
https://github.com/w0lfschild/Flashlight

Answer (score 0):

I often end up going down to the "Show all in Finder" option to get a finder window of results that I can then filter further or order by name/date/type etc.

[spotlight instruction screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oAlml.png)